# How to apply the multiple condition angular ui-tab to add active class?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I am trying to display `menu and sub-menu` using `ui.bootstrap` from angular.js but while selecting submenu the respective parent menu is not getting active class.

dashboard.html:

```
<li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('dashboard.settings.area')}"><a ui-sref="dashboard.settings.area.manageState">Settings</a></li>
```

This is my top parent menu means while click on settings parent menu the below `sub-menu` will open.

settings.html:

```
<div>
<uib-tabset> 

<uib-tab ui-sref="dashboard.settings.area" active="set[1]"> 
<uib-tab-heading>Manage Area</uib-tab-heading>
</uib-tab> 

</uib-tabset> 
<div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

settingscontroller.js:

```
var dept=angular.module('easyride');
dept.controller('settingsController',function($scope,$state){
    $scope.set = {
    1: ($state.current.name === 'dashboard.settings.area')
    };
});
```

Then under this `sub-menu` there is two more `sub-sub-menu` present which are given below.

area.html:

```
<div>
<uib-tabset> 

<uib-tab ui-sref="dashboard.settings.area.manageState" active="area[1]"> 
<uib-tab-heading>Manage State</uib-tab-heading> 
</uib-tab> 

<uib-tab ui-sref="dashboard.settings.area.manageCity" active="area[2]"> 
<uib-tab-heading>Manage City</uib-tab-heading> 
</uib-tab>

</uib-tabset> 
<div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

areacontroller.js:

```
var dept=angular.module('easyride');
dept.controller('areaController',function($scope,$state){
    $scope.area = {
    1: ($state.current.name === 'dashboard.settings.area.manageState'),
    2: ($state.current.name === 'dashboard.settings.area.manageCity')
    };
});
```

When user will click on `settings` `parent menu` it will open the `sub-menu->Manage Area` and under this sub-menu the `sub-sub-menu->Manage State` will open and total chain will remain active. Means `settings,Manage Area,Manage State` three tab will remain active  but in my case only `Manage State` remains active but its parent menu is not highlighting so here I need to put the multiple conditions in `uib-tab` active class.

Comment: This is a bit less chatty than your prior questions, thank you. As an aside, I have removed the quote formatting from your filenames - remember that quote formatting has a special meaning, which is that the material has been "quoted" from elsewhere. So that's speeches, manuals, book excerpts, error messages, etc - but not ordinary text. Thanks!